# How to convert a Spark RDD[Array[MyObject]] into RDD[MyObject]

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

How do I convert a Spark `RDD[Array[MyObject]]` into `RDD[MyObject]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for [`RDD.flatMap`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.1/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD):

```
val flattened: RDD[MyObject] = rdd.flatMap(identity)
```

Comment: I tried what you recommended but getting a syntax error stating that flatMap(_) is missing a parameter. Can you please a small example. Thank you

Comment: @MichaelD try it now.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot!!